# flutter collapsible & expandable button UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

[image]

I am trying to design this UI but I am having problems creating it. Currently using expansion tile but I am not able to get desired results.
This is what I have tried right now

```
          ExpansionTile(
            collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            title: Text("Health"),
            children: [
              Text("children 1"),
              Text("children 2"),
                ElevatedButton(onPressed: (() {}),
                  child: Text('Health'),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  elevation: 1,
                  primary: Colors.amber
          ),
          ),
          ],
  ),
```